# Uber-Api How can I book multiple rides from one corporate account for my customers

Tags: uber-api

Is there any endpoint/api which can allow me to book multiple rides for my customers from a single Uber-account, the customer riding does not have any uber account, If I use **Uber for Business** API it does not allow me to book a second ride and shows conflict 409 error.

Any help ..

Jyoti

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one concurrent ride per `user/token` so the response you get is expected. You need to make a ride request in the sandbox and then progress the state to completed or cancel the ride, and then you can submit new ride request.